# My PHP WebApps are not found when using Apache ProxyPass to connect to Tomcat Java WebApps

Tags: apache, ajp, proxypass

I have apache-http setup using proxypass mod to tomcat:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin john@doe.com
    ServerName <my domain>.com
    ServerAlias www.<my domain>.com
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8080/<web-app context root>/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/<web-app context root>/
    ErrorLog logs/<my domain>.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/<my domain>.com-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Using this configuration all the traffic is forwarded on great.

However, I also have some php pages on the apache and with this configuration I get a HTTP-404.

Is it possible to mix php sites and have this setup with java hosted sites too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add exclusions using ! syntax.

```
ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !
```